# EditText box not shown

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

I am trying to make a simple android application. I ma using the android version 2.3.3. I have used the following code for displaying a EditText box in my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/username"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/remember_me"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remember_me"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/signInButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/signIn" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/forgot_password"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/createAccountButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/create_account" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But the EditText is not being displayed. All other buttons, textviews and everything are being displayed properly, only the EditText are not being shown. Can anyone please tell me what the problem is??
-Thanks in advance

Comment: Just restart Eclipse once. Could be an Eclipse bug.

Comment: Please Provide full code of your xml file.

Comment: please can you post the entire xml code? i think once clean the project then it will be working fine.

Comment: Just tried that, did not work :(

Comment: @relsell just check, i posted my entire xml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText   android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Actually my TextView itself was set to fill_parent, therefore there was no space left for the EditText.

Comment: Please add an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its happens b'coz of the textview has width attribute as fill parent / match parent, so that the textview fill(width) the screen, then the edit text go out of visible area. to solve this follow the one of following method..

1. set textview width as **wrap_content or fixed width (ex 50dp)**. if u used wrap_content then again edit text may go out of visible area by depending on text in text view.
2. set **both text view and edit text's width** as **layout_width="match_parent"** and add one more attribute **layout_weight="1"**. now both text view and edit text equally share the share the width of parent.

   ```
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent" layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/username"
           android:textColor="#000000" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/username"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:inputType="text"
           android:text="" >

           <requestFocus />
       </EditText>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Give the id for TextView and put EditText below to the TextView

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/testview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/username"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/textview1"
    android:text=""
    android:inputType="text" >
```